# Netbeans Find Usages on class references from (non-open) Maven artifacts

Tags: maven, netbeans, netbeans-7.4, code-navigation

Is there a setting in Netbeans when we do Find Usages.
i.e. Find Usages on class references from (non-open) Maven artifacts

Can we turn ON/OFF for finding in Maven repositories ?

I am using the latest Netbeans 7.4

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a setting in Netbeans when we do Find Usages. i.e. Find Usages on class references from (non-open) Maven artifacts

There isn't such a setting (As far as I know).

> Can we turn ON/OFF for finding in Maven repositories ?

If you refer to `Find Usages` (`ALT` + `F7`) there isn't such a setting (As far as I know).

If you refer to `Find in Projects...` (`ALT` + `SHIFT` + `F7`) you then have to select a `scope` but, unfortunately, there is not any "sources in local Maven repository".